# How to set focus to date portion of DateTimePicker that has a checkbox?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am using a regular vanilla DateTimePicker (DTP) in Windows Forms. The user has requested that when the window opens, the DTP is selected so they can immediately edit the date with the keyboard.

It is a DTP with a checkbox enabled, and so when I use the standard

```
DTP.Select()
```

it selects the checkbox, not the date-part of the control, which achieves nothing useful for the user.

I am sensing there is no way around this beyond hacks like `SendKeys`, which I will resort to if nobody has a good solution.

Thought I'd check with the boffins!

Comment: You need the SendKeys hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must select the portion after it has the focus

For example :

```
SwitchToThisWindow(DTP.Handle, true);
SendKeys.Send("{RIGHT}");
```

with declaration :

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Boolean fAltTab);
```

Comment: Basically there's no way to do it without the sendkeys, fair enough thanks